# Combining dummies and count for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, dummy-variable

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

[image: original table]

as a plain text:

> {'id;sub_id;value;total_stuff related to id and sub_id':
> ['aaa;1;cat;10', 'aaa;1;cat;10', 'aaa;1;dog;10', 'aaa;2;cat;7',
> 'aaa;2;dog;7', 'aaa;3;cat;5', 'bbb;1;panda;20', 'bbb;1;cat;20',
> 'bbb;2;panda;12']}

The desired output I want is this.

[image: desired output]

Note that there are many different "values" possible, so I would need to automate the creation of dummies variables (nb_animals).
But these dummies variables must contain the number of occurences by id and sub_id.
The total_stuff is always the same value for a given id/sub_id combination.

I've tried using `get_dummies(df, columns = ['value'])`, which gave me this table.

[using get_dummies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxoBR.png)

as a plain text:

> {'id;sub_id;value_cat;value_dog;value_panda;total_stuff related to id
> and sub_id': ['aaa;1;2;1;0;10', 'aaa;1;2;1;0;10', 'aaa;1;2;1;0;10',
> 'aaa;2;1;1;0;7', 'aaa;2;1;1;0;7', 'aaa;3;1;0;0;5', 'bbb;1;1;0;1;20',
> 'bbb;1;1;0;1;20', 'bbb;2;0;0;1;12']}

I'd love to use some kind of `df.groupby(['id','sub_id']).agg({'value_cat':'sum', 'value_dog':'sum',  ... , 'total_stuff':'mean'})`, but writing all of the possible animal values would be too tedious.

So how to get a proper aggregated count/sum for values, and average for total_stuff (since total_stuff is unique per id/sub_id combination)

Thanks

EDIT : Thanks chikich for the neat answer. The agg_dict is what I needed

Comment: Please update your post with your sample dataframe as plain text. You can use `print(pd.read_csv('sample.csv').to_dict('list'))`.

Comment: {'id;sub_id;value;total_stuff related to id and sub_id': ['aaa;1;cat;10', 'aaa;1;cat;10', 'aaa;1;dog;10', 'aaa;2;cat;7', 'aaa;2;dog;7', 'aaa;3;cat;5', 'bbb;1;panda;20', 'bbb;1;cat;20', 'bbb;2;panda;12']}


My real table has more columns than the example I provided, I'll refactor the code

Comment: I modified the original post. Sorry my original post wasn't detailled enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.get_dummies` to transform categorical data

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='nb', columns='value')
```

Then group by id and subid

```
agg_dict = {key: 'sum' for key in df.columns if key[:3] == 'nb_'}
agg_dict['total_stuff'] = 'mean'
df = df.groupby(['id', 'subid']).agg(agg_dict).reset_index()
```